# Sprite Images work locally but not live

Tags: css, sprite

My final is due tomorrow and I can't figure out why my sprite images aren't loading when I upload them to my .ftp. When I view them locally they work but not one the server. Someone please help!!

http://bccvisualdesign.com/art271/simmons/final/index.html

they are located at the bottom left of the screen.

Comment: Be sure you uploaded your image

Comment: I am, everything is uploaded.

Comment: In your CSS you have: `background: url(../images/social.png) -66px 0px;` So it is looking for them here: http://bccvisualdesign.com/art271/simmons/final/images/social.png  ... which does not exist (404 error).

Comment: What is weird is that if you go to  bccvisualdesign.com/art271/simmons/final/images/

Comment: If you have a `.htaccess` file, try clearing out any rules you have in there to see if that allows the image load. Or maybe delete and re-upload it. If that doesn't work, I'd contact your web host for help. Might be a permissions thing.

Comment: I renamed the image and the server accepted it, weird